# Why is color priority not applied in the div?

Tags: html, css

The color of all text is blue, but I want it to be black in this div as specified in the style, but it does not apply. Someone can help please?

```css
body {
    background-color: #cfc;
}

h1 {
    color: #f00;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    size: 32px;
}

h2 {
    color: #a00;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    size: 24px;
}

p,
ul,
li {
    color: #00f;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    size: 16px;
}

.titles {
    color: #000 !important;
    font-style: italic !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="titles">
    <ul>
        <li>Example 1</li>
        <li>Example 2</li>
        <li>Example 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using only `.title` as a selector. Within `.title`, there is only `ul` element, that by itself does not contain any text. The `li` tags are the ones that contain the text, so you need to select them, not the whole parent. You can do that simply by adding the `li` to the selector.

```
    .titles li {
        color: #000;
        font-style: italic;
    }
```

[Check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors) for more context and info.